# Represent double like a integer of 3 digits

Tags: .net, string-formatting

```
?string.Format("{0:D3}", 10/2)
{"Format specifier was invalid."}
    _HResult: -2146233033
    _message: "Format specifier was invalid."
```

I need to represent a double like a integer of 3 digits. Say "5.2" should be represented as "005" and say "5.9" should be better as "006" but is OK even if it is "005".

Does the Framework not support representing a Double like a Integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative solution to use

`?string.Format("{0:000}", 5.9)` instead.

I can't use "D" or "d" specifier because it is "Supported by: Integral types only." ([Standard Numeric Format Strings - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.Round` to round to an integer (optional), then cast to `int` before using the `D3` format:

```
string.Format("{0:D3}", (int)Math.Round(10/2));
```

Casting to `int` prevents the "invalid format specifier" error, which occurs because you provide an integer formatting option for a floating point argument.

Comment: why this "invalid specifier error" occurs? I just want to format my double in a documented way...

Comment: @serhio: I edited the answer to include that, perhaps you didn't catch it in time.